# Problem with query in a loop in QGIS Script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to run the following script in QGIS

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

inLayer = iface.activeLayer()

with open('iso_codes.txt') as f:
  codes = f.readlines()

for isoCode in codes:
  #exp = QgsExpression('"ISO_CODE" = \'AF\'') # THIS WORKS
  exp = QgsExpression('"ISO_CODE" = \'%s\'' % isoCode) # THIS DOES NOT WORK
  request = QgsFeatureRequest( exp )
  fipsCode = ''
  for feature in inLayer.getFeatures( request ):
    fips = feature['FIPS_CODE']
    if fipsCode != fips:
      fipsCode = fips
      print '%s, %s' % (isoCode, fipsCode)
```

Using **'"ISO_CODE" = \'AF\''** as argument the script works till the end.

Using ***'"ISO_CODE" = \'%s\'' % isoCode*** as argument the script doesn't go into the for loop.

I've tried to use **inLayer.setSelectedFeatures([])** at the end of the for loop, but this did not help.

Comment: Did you try lower case s?  '"ISO_CODE" = \'%s\'' % isoCode

Comment: The '%s' as upper case has been a type mistake. I've corrected the example code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readlines()` does not strip newline characters (\n) or carriage return characters (\r) from the read string. What you have read is most likely not the string 'AF' but 'AF\n', and that's why equality is not true for any feature in your layer.

Instead of:

```
# line with newline character
with open('e:\iso_codes.txt') as f:
    codes = f.readlines()
    for code in codes:
        print code

DE

AF

US
```

Try something like that:

```
with open('e:\iso_codes.txt') as f:
    codes = f.read().splitlines()
    for code in codes:
        print code

# line with newline character stripped off
with open('e:\iso_codes.txt') as f:
    codes = f.readlines()
    for code in codes:
        print code[:-1]

# line splitted manually, skipping the last newline
with open('e:\iso_codes.txt') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    codes = contents.split('\n')
    for code in codes[:-1]:
        print code

DE
AF
US
```

Answer (score 1):

As Richard Morgan suggest you, try a lower case for the 's' (s instead of S). But a another suggestion if it's still doesn't work. Try to use the format method of the string class. It's available since Python 2.7 :

```
with open('iso_codes.txt') as f:
    codes = f.readlines()

    for isoCode in codes:
        #exp = QgsExpression('"ISO_CODE" = \'AF\'') # THIS WORKS
        exp = QgsExpression('"ISO_CODE" = \'{}\''.format(isoCode)) # THIS SHOULD WORK

        try:
            if exp.hasParserError :
                raise Exception(exp.parserErrorString())
            if exp.hasEvalError:
                raise ValueError(exp.evalErrorString())
            request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
            fipsCode = ''
            for feature in inLayer.getFeatures( request ):
                fips = feature['FIPS_CODE']
                if fipsCode != fips:
                    fipsCode = fips
                    print '{}, {}'.format(isoCode, fipsCode) # I ALSO EDIT HERE
        except Exception as e:
            print "it has an error in expression :  {}".format(e)
        except ValueError as v:
            print "The expression is good but it can't be evaluate error : {}".format(v)
```

-- EDIT --

I update the code so you can handle errors I suspect that some lines can raise errors but not all of them. And you can see what happen with error lines.

Comment: Thank you SIGIS for the advice, but does not work. I've tried differents combinations, but nothing seams to work :( Something is wrong with QgsExpression() ???

Comment: Have you tried to validate your expression ? QgsExpression() has a method called hasParserError()